# Cómo redondear a la cifra entera superior solo si el importe no es un valor entero

Tags: symfony3, twig

Tengo la siguiente situación, y les reflejo la imagen para ubicarlos, además del código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente lista de bultos, la última columna refleja el precio de cada bulto que desea enviar un determinado cliente en un container. El precio de cada bulto está redondeado a 2 decimales y es el volumen del bulto redondeado a 2 decimales por el precio establecido para el metro cúbico, pero el importe total (enmarcado en rojo al final de la columna) se le refleja al cliente como un valor entero, de manera tal que si el producto del volumen ocupado por el cliente por el precio del metro cúbico, da un valor con decimal se redondea al entero superior, independientemente de si el redondeo es por exceso o defecto; para ello se aplica la opción `"ceil"` a la función `round` de la vista `twig`.
Este es el código que genera la tabla con el `footer` donde está el importe total:

```
<tbody>
    {% set volumenTotal = 0 %}
    {% set pesoVolTotal = 0 %}
    {% set peso = 0 %}
    {% set importeTotal = 0 %}
    {% for bulto in bultos %}
        <tr>        
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.numero}}</td>
            <td class="text-justify">{{bulto.descripcion}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.dimensionLargo}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.dimensionAncho}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.dimensionAlto}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.volumen|number_format('6','.',',')}} ({{bulto.volumen|number_format('2','.',',')}})</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.pesoVolumetrico}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{bulto.peso}}</td>
            {% set precioBulto = bulto.precioACostometrocubicoActual %}
            <td class="text-right">{{precioBulto|number_format('2','.',',')}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% set volumenTotal = volumenTotal + (bulto.volumen|round(2)) %}
        {% set pesoVolTotal = pesoVolTotal+bulto.pesoVolumetrico %}
        {% set peso = peso + bulto.peso %}
        {% set importeTotal = importeTotal + precioBulto %} 
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
<tfoot>
{% if bultos is empty %}
    <tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>
{% endif %}
    <tr class="bg-primary">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>        
        <th class="text-center text-bold">{{volumenTotal|number_format('2','.',',')}}</th>
        <th class="text-center text-bold">{{pesoVolTotal|number_format('2','.',',')}}</th>
        <th class="text-center text-bold">{{peso|number_format('2','.',',')}}</th>
        <th class="text-right text-bold">{{(volumenTotal*colaborador.menaje.precioMetroCubico)|round(0,'ceil')|number_format(2,'.',',')}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

De la forma en que se calcula en la vista el importe, como se le está pasando el parámetro `ceil` a la función `round` de `Twig`, si el resultado del importe total da un valor entero, la funcion round, le está subiendo 1 entero más. Digamos que el importe da 450.00, entonces se eleva a 451.00 (caso incorrecto), pero si el importe diera 449.10 ó 449.75 que es el caso de la imagen, entonces el importe sería 450.00 (caso correcto).

Cómo enfoco este cálculo para que de el valor adecuado. Al final de la tabla hay dos notas para el usuario, que expresan la forma en que se calcula el importe final, que en resumen es lo que deseo lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución encontrada es la siguiente, mediante la implementación de un filtro `Twig`.

```
class UuidExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(               
            new TwigFilter('importe_formatter', array($this, 'formatearImporteMenaje'))
        );
    }

       
    public function formatearImporteMenaje($importe) {
        $resultado = 0;
        if (is_int($importe) || ctype_digit($importe)) {
            $resultado = number_format($importe, 2, ',', '.');
        } else {
            $resultado = number_format(round($importe, 0, 4), 2, ',', '.');
        }

        return $resultado;
    }

}
```

El filtro 'importe_formatter', verifica si el valor del importe es un entero, en ese caso solo formatea a 2 decimales; en caso contrario, redondea al entero superior y formatea a 2 decimales.

y en la vista Twig, en el footer de la tabla se emplea en la última columna:

```
<th class="text-right text-bold">{{importeTotal|importe_formatter}}</th>
```